# combine two javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've have been trying to fix this problem.

Here is the code:

```
<h4>Your Itinerary</h4>
<div id="selected"></div>
<script>
    (function () {  
        $(".info-css").on(
            'click' 
        ,   function (e) {
                $('#selected').html(
                    [
                        $('#start option:selected').text()                        
                    ,   $('#second option:selected').text()                       
                    ,   $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" )
                    ,   $('#third option:selected').text()
                    ,   $("#datepicker2").datepicker( "getDate" )
                    ,   $('#forth option:selected').text()
                    ,   $("#datepicker3").datepicker( "getDate" )
                    ].join("<br> to ")
                );
            }
        );
    }());
</script>
```

The code outputs something like this:

```
Your Itinerary

Arenal / la Fortuna

to Cahuita

to Mon Mar 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time (Mexico))

to Bocas del Toro (To/From Costa Rica)

to Thu Mar 24 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time (Mexico))

to Manzanillo

to Thu Mar 31 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time (Mexico))
```

I'm trying to do two things:

1) Have the `getDate` only show the `Mon Mar 21 2016` and not the time and everything else.

2) Combine the

```
    $('#second option:selected').text()
,   $("#datepicker").datepicker( "getDate" )
```

into one string with `on` between the two.

For Example:

```
Arenal / la Fortuna
```

to:

```
Cahuita on Mon Mar 21 2016
```

Here is a test page:

http://thecostaricatoursite.tcct-test.com/test/

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to set the `dateFormat` that the `datepicker` will return by doing the following:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'D M dd yy' });
```

Notes: You can refer to `jquery.datepicker` document for more information on how to select the format for date [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Then get the value of the selected date from the input instead of from `getDate` to avoid parsing `Date` object because `getDate` return a `Date` instead of a `string`.

```
$("#datepicker").val()
```

Your code to display the itinerary is a comma separated array of string. Thus to combine the destinate with the date you could do the following

```
$('#second option:selected').text() + ' on ' + $("#datepicker").val()
```

which would treat this as a single element of an array instead of two like your original code. Repeat the same for the rest of your selected date and you will get the result you like.

Good luck!!